# How to match exact phrase with dynamic string in text index Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this query

```
db.words.find({ "$text": { "$search": "\"cake sale\"" } }) // gives expected answer in robo3T
```

Now my `text` search is dynamic

```
const text = "cake sale"
db.words.find({ "$text": { "$search": `\\"${text}\\"` } })
```

But it does not give me expected output with nodejs. So How can I parse the backslash here?

Comment: You have an extra quote right after the backtick in your second example. So you're searching for ""cake sale" instead of "cake sale"

Comment: Your query doesn't match the syntax shown in the docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/
`db.stores.find( { $text: { $search: "\"coffee shop\"" } } )` 

It has an additional double quote at the end. So just add that last `"` at the end

Comment: @nopassport1 Yes you are right. But still could you show me how can we do that with dynamic string?

Comment: I guess: `db.words.find({ "$text": { "$search": `"\\"${text}\\""` } })`? But your search query should just be "cake sale"

Comment: @nopassport1 No... My query should be \"cake sale\"

Comment: Then it should be ` `\\"${text}\\"` `

Answer (score 2):

Your query is incorrect. You need to change the query

```
db.words.find({ "$text": { "$search": `"\"${text}\"` } })
```

to

```
db.words.find({ "$text": { "$search": `\"${text}\"` } })
```

Since, there is an extra double quote (`"`) in the beginning after the first backquote. Doing that will fix your query.

Simple illustration:

```js
console.log("\"cake sale\"");

var text = "cake sale";
console.log(`\"${text}\"`);
// both the console.log gives same result
```

Comment: No the log should show \"cake sale\" – Dark Knight 8 mins ago    Delete

Comment: May not have been marked as the correct answer but this worked for me. Thank you.